# Is the operator norm of $T(f)=\intop f(x)g(x)dx$ always $\intop \mid g(x) \mid dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X = (C[0,1],\mid\mid\cdot\mid\mid _\infty)$ be the space of continuous functions on the closed interval $[0,1]$ with the supremum norm. Let $g(x)$ be a continuous function in this interval, and define with it the following linear operator: $$T(f)=\intop_0^1 f(x)\cdot g(x)\ dx$$
It is easy to see that $\mid\mid T \mid\mid_{op} \leq \intop_0^1 \mid g(x)\mid dx$. If $g(x)$ changes signs a finite number if times, one can also show that this inequality is in fact an equality, since we can define: $f(x)=1\cdot sgn(g)$
And connect the discontinuous points of this function using linear slopes. A sequence of such functions, built in such a way that the slopes become steeper with each element of the sequence will show:
$$lim \mid T(f_n)\mid = \intop_0^1 \mid g(x)\mid dx$$

Does this equality hold for every continuous $g(x)$?

Comment: Yes, continuous functions are dense in $L_1([0,1])$, hence you can approximate function $f = sgn(g)$ by sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions such that $f_n \to f$ in $L_1([0,1])$. In particular $ \int_0^1 f_n(x)g(x)dx \to \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx = \int_0^1 |g(x)|dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the most elementary way to see this is the one that Dominik Kutek states in the comments. But, if one is okay with the Riesz representation theorem, one can see this directly: the functional $f\mapsto\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$ is equal to the functional $f\mapsto\int_0^1f(x)d\mu(x)$, where $\mu$ is the Borel measure $\mu(E):=\int_Eg(x)dx$. The norm of any functional of the form $f\mapsto\int_0^1fd\mu$ is precisely the total variation of the measure $\mu$, thanks to the Riesz representation theorem. It is a simple exercise to check that the total variation of the measure $\mu(E)=\int_Eg(x)dx$ is equal to $\int_X|g(x)|dx$.

I'm posting this as a "big picture" view of the situation. Of course the same thing can be stated for any compact Hausdorff space.